# how to convert hash with many sub level item to non sub item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to convert a hash with many level sub item to hash only a one level.
Example:

```
Input:
{"a1"=>{"a11"=>11, "a12"=>12, "a13"=>13, "a14" => {"a141" => 141} }}

Output:
{"a[a11]" => 11, "a[a12]" => 12, "a[a13]" => 13, "a[a14][a141]" => 141}
```

How to slove above problem?

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to do something with checkboxes that you shouldn't. What is the original problem?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "don't working" mean? Do you get an error message? If yes, what does it say? What line does it point to? Do you get any output? If yes, what output do you get? What output do you expect, and why? And what does this have to with [tag:ruby-on-rails]?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, to be fair, I think that tagging something as [tag:ruby-on-rails] if you mean *"I accept active support dependent solutions"* is appropriate.

Comment: Why not tag it [tag:activesupport], then?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, (1) not all people know that it exists, what is it for and what are the boundaries, (2) not a lot of people follow the tag, (3) if I see [tag:activesupport] I would expect questions more in the line of *"how does this work"*, rather than *"how can I do this with ruby/rails"*.

Answer (score 0):

A Hash key can be any object. I would first build the new key as an array and after this convert it back into a string:

```
def convert_keys(in_hash ={})
  in_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), result|
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      convert_keys(value).each_pair do |converted_key, converted_value|
        new_key = [ key ] + converted_key
        result[new_key] = converted_value
      end
    else
      result[ [key] ] = value
    end
  end
end

def parse_params(in_hash ={})
  convert_keys(in_hash).each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), result|
    key_postfix = key[1..-1].map { |key_part| "[#{key_part}]" }.join
    str_key =  "#{key[0]}#{key_postfix}"

    result[str_key] = value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take it:

```
a = {"a1"=>{"a11"=>11, "a12"=>12, "a13"=>13, "a14" => {"a141" => 141} }}

def modi(hash)
  hash.map do |key, value|
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      value = modi(value).flatten(1)
      ["[#{key}]" + value.first, value.last]
    else
      ["[#{key}]", value]
    end
  end 
end

def pars(main_hash)
  main_hash.map do |key, value|
    modi(value).each_with_object({}) do |v, res|
      res[v.first.prepend(key.first)] = v.last
    end 
  end.first #*
end 

pars(a)
> {"a[a11]"=>11, "a[a12]"=>12, "a[a13]"=>13, "a[a14][a141]"=>141}
```

*. or you can remove `first` method and then it return:

```
[{"a[a11]"=>11, "a[a12]"=>12, "a[a13]"=>13, "a[a14][a141]"=>141}]
```

this can help you, if in future you'll add some new functionality, for example, input will be: `

```
a = {"a1"=>{"a11"=>11, "a12"=>12, "a13"=>13, "a14"=>{"a141"=>141}}, "b1"=>{"b11"=>11}}
```

then, without `first` this method return:

```
[{"a[a11]"=>11, "a[a12]"=>12, "a[a13]"=>13, "a[a14][a141]"=>141,{"b[b11]"=>11}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If, given your input above, your desired output was

```
{"a1[a11]" => 11, "a1[a12]" => 12, "a1[a13]" => 13, "a1[a14][a141]" => 141}
```

This method should work:

```rb
def convert_hash(hash, depth = 0, keys = [], memo = {})
  hash.each do |key, value|
    keys = keys.first(depth) << key
    if value.is_a? Hash
      convert_hash(value, depth + 1, keys, memo)
    else
      head, *tail = keys
      # if there was no typo in your question, then use `head.first` here
      converted_key = tail.reduce(head) { |memo, key| "#{memo}[#{key}]"}
      memo[converted_key] = value
    end
  end
  memo
end

(pry)> convert_hash({"a1"=>{"a11"=>11, "a12"=>12, "a13"=>13, "a14"=>{"a141"=>141}}})
 => {"a1[a11]"=>11, "a1[a12]"=>12, "a1[a13]"=>13, "a1[a14][a141]"=>141}
```